# Unity2D - Implementing Linecast2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know HOW linecast is supposed to work but I just can't figure out how to properly implement it in my code.

Basically what I have is a player that can dig down through dirt atm. I've got it working so when the user presses S it digs down and destroys the object. What I am trying to do is to have the line cast start at the player and end a short distance later (say about .5f away) and when that happens, the player digs through the dirt on the right side.

I've got a couple layers of dirt all with their own box colliders all with the same tag "Dirt".

Where I run into trouble is trying to work out the arguments. I've got a `Vector2` named `playerPos` which gets the players location (the beginning argument for `Physics2d.Linecast`). I've also got a `Vector2` for `blockPos` but I don't know how to initialise that without issues from the dirt object below the player.

Are there any full start to finish new project -> loading sprites -> coding -> full play tutorials I can go through, I've looked at YouTube videos and stuff but they only seem to show the initialisation of `Linecast` and not the process before it.

I am really lost at this point with `Linecast` and would really appreciate something to set me back on track.

Comment: Please provide the code you are using so it is easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've also got a `Vector2` for `blockPos` but I don't know how to initialise that without issues from the dirt object below the player.

Vector math.

```
Vector2 blockPos = playerPos + Vector2.Down * maxDistance;
```

Where `maxDistance` is the longest distance away from the player's position that you want the line to cast out to, probably only 1 or 2 units.

Comment: Thanks but I was able to figure it out. Didn't realise a raycast tutorial would also give me a Linecast tut aswell. I'll mark as correct because this would work as well though.